# CPU mining Core 2 Quad Q9550

Tags: cpu-mining, cpu, cpuminer

I am new to mining and not actually mining Bitcoin right now but want to understand more about it.

I have Core 2 Quad Q9550 CPU at 2.83 Ghz. I am mining with cpuminer only right now. I am getting 20 h/s on each core so 80 h/s for 4 cores.

When I put -t 8 for 8 threads I get around 11 h/s. Since this CPU doesn't support more than 4 threads at a time. What would be faster? more threads or 4 threads? or just 2 threads?

Curious to learn.

EDIT: I feel setting cpuminer to 8 threads generates more h/s.

Answer (score 1):

-t 6 threads should be the best setting, half of the L3 cache. Give it a try and let us know how it goes. Also, see what the developer of xmrig (cpuminer 'competitor') says about it:

xmrig commented on Aug 29, 2017

"...Also 6 threads per CPU/Node is optimal, because of 12 MB L3 cache, each thread required 2 MB cache for optimal performance, more threads less hashrate. So 12 threads is optimal anyway, just need separate it."